# color change of <p:commandButton> after every onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code in jsf page is shown below,with below code i am getting popup for every click but at the same time i want to change color p:commandButton for every click.

```
<h:form id="form">

 <p:commandButton id="button01" oncomplete="PF('test01').show()" value="sysno_01" icon="button" update=":form01:dialog01" />
</h:form>

  <h:form id="form01">
         <p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="test01" id="dialog01"
            resizable="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

            <p:panelGrid id="display01" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value=" First name" />
            <h:inputText id="fnme01" value="#{studentLoginBean.studentname}" />
            <h:outputText value=" last name" />
            <h:inputText id="lnme01" value="#{studentLoginBean.lastname}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{studentLoginBean.login}" value="Login">
             <f:param name="action" value="01" />
            </h:commandButton>  
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{studentLoginBean.logout}" value="Logout">
                <f:param name="action" value="01" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </p:dialog> 
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : put `class="changeColor"` for each button as shown below

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{studentLoginBean.login}" value="Login" class="changeColor">
         <f:param name="action" value="01" />
</h:commandButton>  
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{studentLoginBean.logout}" value="Logout" class="changeColor">
            <f:param name="action" value="01" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Then register a jquery click handler on it and change its color

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         var colors = ['red','green','blue','pink','yellow','gray','white'];
         var len = colors.length;
         var counter = 0;
         $('.changeColor').click(function(){
             $(this).css('background-color', colors[counter]);
             counter++;
             //reset counter
             if(counter==len)
               counter = 0;
         });
    });
</scrip>
```

Comment: put whole code (code with `<script>` tag) under `<head>` tag of your page or inside `<body>` tag is also fine.

Comment: i want change color of p:commandButton after click with popup

Comment: So you want to change button color on every click of `<p:dialog`. You mean to change color when user click anywhere on opened popup?

Comment: `<p:commandButton id="button01" oncomplete="PF('test01').show()"` this button click is opening a popup and when popup shows you want to change color of buttons? You want both button inside popup with same or different colors?

Comment: then above code will do just add `class="changeColor"` to that button and remove it from popup button

Comment: You should have specify the button id `id="button01"` as there are other button in your html code provided by you. This create confusion while answering. be careful next time ... have good day